# Вывод данных в обратном порядке

Tags: php, mysql

Вывожу циклом `do while` новости на страницу по `id`, но при добавлении новой новости, она появляется в самом низу. Как запустить цикл в обратном порядке?

Вот код:

```
        do {
          if(!$myrow['img']){
            printf ("
              <div class='news_content'>
                <a href='/news?id=%d'><img src='images_site/no-image.png'/></a>
                <div class='news_main'>
                  <p class='time_comment'>%s</p>
                  <a href='/news?id=%d'><h4 class='time_comment'>%s</h4></a>
                  <p class='time_comment_p'>%s</p>
                  <a class='readon' href='/news?id=%d'>Читать продолжение</a>
                </div>
              </div>", $myrow['id'], $myrow['date'], $myrow['id'], $myrow['title'], $result, $myrow['id']);
          }
          else {
            printf ("
              <div class='news_content'>
                <a href='/news?id=%d'><img src='%s'/></a>
                <div class='news_main'>
                  <p class='time_comment'>%s</p>
                  <a href='/news?id=%d'><h4 class='time_comment'>%s</h4></a>
                  <p class='time_comment_p'>%s</p>
                  <a class='readon' href='/news?id=%d'>Читать продолжение</a>
                </div>
              </div>", $myrow['id'], $myrow['img'], $myrow['date'], $myrow['id'], $myrow['title'], $result, $myrow['id']);
          }
        }
        while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($resylt));`
```

Comment: самый разумный вариант - изменить `ORDER BY` в запросе, чтобы данные попадали в `$resylt` уже в нужном Вам порядке

Comment: do{}while() выдёт курсы Попова. Не делайте так, иначе будете периодически получать странные ошибки. Пользуйтесь обычным while(){}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделать запрос

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY id DESC
```

Попробуйте.

Comment: Спасибо большое помогло "ORDER BY id DESC".
Расформулируйте пожалуйста что за действие это "ORDER BY id DESC"?

Comment: Все изменилось, только теперь текст в уроках один и тот же(( Что делать?